# TSQL, How can I group rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

In SQL Server 2008, I have this result:

```
 contact  phone       address    email
 Name1    435551123     
 Name1                street 1  
 Name1                           name1@domain.com
 Name2    654987624
 Name2                street2   
 Name2                           name2@domanin.com
```

and I want to "compress" it like the following:

```
 contact  phone       address    email
 Name1    435551123   street 1   name1@domain.com       
 Name2    654987624   street2    name2@domanin.com
```

Comment: Show me your query at http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: normalize your table..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the Query

```
select
contact,
max(phone),
max(address),
max(email)
from table_name
group by contact
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a9d78/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and some [`OVER` clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT [contact], 
         [phone]=MAX(PHONE)OVER(PARTITION BY CONTACT), 
         [address]=MAX(address)OVER(PARTITION BY CONTACT),  
         [email]=MAX(email)OVER(PARTITION BY CONTACT),  
          RN = Row_number() 
                OVER( 
                partition BY [contact] 
                ORDER BY [contact])
  FROM dbo.Address) 
SELECT [contact], [phone], [address], [email] 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
CONTACT PHONE       ADDRESS         EMAIL
Name1   435551123   street 1        name1@domain.com
Name2   654987624   street2         name2@domanin.com
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abd17/8/1)